# Какая польза от перехода на managed language's?

Tags: c#, .net, java

А точнее, зачем их вообще используют и зачем (в каких ситуациях) лучше их использовать?
Вот посудите сами.
Managed languages:

1. Выполняются в виртуальной машине (соответственно, требуют больше инструкций для выполнения инструкций языка)
2. Являются интерпретируемыми (выходит из первого пункта), соответственно, требуют больше памяти\ресурсов машины, а значит, программы написанные с их использованием работают медленнее, требуют больше ресурсов, вычислений, и т.п.

В то время как программы, написанные (скомпилированные прямо в машинный код) на "обычных" процедурных\объектно-ориентированных языках, вроде того же С или С++, обладают куда большей скоростью, производительностью, куда менее требовательны к памяти и ресурсам системы.

И почему, к примеру, если я хочу использовать в своей программе систему классов NET Framework, я *обязан* перейти на виртуальную машину? Что, если я хочу, чтобы мой код компилировался в машинный?

Например, мой одногрупник решил писать на Java, мотивируя свой переход с плюсов на яву тем, что в C++, якобы, нужно иметь дело со "всеми этими указателями" (и он даже ничего не слышал ни про *RAII*, ни про *smart ptr*'ы), а в Jave, вот, есть *GarbageCollector*, и ни о чем думать и заботиться не надо.

В чем же причина такого массового распространения managed языков, какую нишу они занимают, и какая судьба в будущем ждет языки вроде С,C++, Haskell, и т.д.?

Comment: Все это зависит от задачи, адекватный человек не будет писать на C++ приложение в котором нужно организовать 500 форм и доступ к БД через сеть.Также он не будет писать компьютерную игру на C#. Меняются задачи, меняется инструмент.

Comment: > В худшем случае про него могут только забыть.

Чем не смерть? =)

Comment: Но ведь теоретически могут и вспомнить :-) А то что умерло уже никак не вернешь назад. Поэтому аналогия между смертью и забвеньем плоха.

Comment: @stremm Насчёт скорости выполнения. Пару десятков лет один француз писал об этом: http://gallium.inria.fr/~xleroy/bibrefs/Leroy-ZINC.html

@igumnov живучесть языков определяется количеством используемого кода. Так что Кобол -- жив. Результаты афёры Y2K это в прошлом веке продемонстрировали.

Comment: > Также он не будет писать компьютерную игру на C#. 

Весьма спорно. Чем C# помешает написать компьютерную игру (именно игру, а не граф. движок)? Managed-языки куда приятнее для описания иерархии игровых объектов и игровой механики.

Comment: Также он не будет писать компьютерную игру на C#.

лолшто? На шарпе очень даже можно писать игры, вполне себе быстрые и красивые

Comment: - Сам вопрос какой-то мутный. Почему в таком случае не спросить, например, как писать сайты на машинном коде. `Javascript` под `V8` же выполняется на виртуальной машине, а я, скажем, хочу, чтобы мой сайт компилировался в машинный код.

- Все `managed` языки решают определенный спектр задач. И разговор о выборе  языка / платформы / компилятора / дополнительных тулз имеет смысл только тогда, когда **точно сформулирована задача.** А так разговор неконструктивен - ну да, `IL, GC, JIT`. Ну да, в `C++` не так.

- Никто, кстати, не упомянул про [`NGEN`.](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngen)

Comment: Почему-то все начинающие программисты зацикливаются на скорости. Хотя ПРАКТИКА показывает, что, к примеру, довольно нагруженные сайты успешно функционируют на сравнительно медленных Python и Ruby. В работе реальной системы значительная часть производительности зависит не от языка, а, к примеру, от базы данных. Но, если уж Вас так смущает скорость, то посмотрите на Хаскель и Го - они компилируются, виртуальных машин не держат, однако управление памятью присутствует.

Comment: Кстати, вы можете писать приложение на C++ и при этом использовать библиотеку классов .NET. У вас здесь вообще нет никаких припятствий.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Являются интерпретируемыми (выходит из первого пункта), соответственно, требуют больше памяти\ресурсов машины, а значит, программы написанные с их использованием работают медленнее, требуют больше ресурсов, вычислений, и т.п.
>
> В то время как программы, написанные (скомпилированные прямо в машинный код) на "обычных" процедурных\объектно-ориентированных языках, вроде того же С или С++, обладают куда большей скоростью, производительностью, куда менее требовательны к памяти и ресурсам системы.

Это спорно.

Во-первых, в современных средах используют агрессивный JIT, который может выдавать код исполняющийся быстрее чем тот что компилируется статически (ниже занятный пример такого превосходства), за счёт дополнительной информации доступной только в рантайме.

Во-вторых, обычно на всю систему запускается одна виртуальная машина, для множества приложений использующих её, в то время как каждая программа скомпилированная статически тащит необходимый рантайм каждая свой. На самом деле это несущественно, но стоит упомянуть.

> И почему, к примеру, если я хочу использовать в своей программе систему классов NET Framework, я обязан перейти на виртуальную машину? Что, если я хочу, чтобы мой код компилировался в машинный?

Тогда вам наверное не по пути.

> Например, мой одногрупник решил писать на Java, мотивируя свой переход с плюсов на яву тем, что в C++, якобы, нужно иметь дело со "всеми этими указателями" (и он даже ничего не слышал ни про RAII, ни про smart ptr'ы), а в Jave, вот, есть GarbageCollector, и ни о чем думать и заботиться не надо.

У вашего одногруппника очень здравая позиция, он выбирает функционал и избегает лишней сложности. Это ведь великолепно, что GC снимает часть головной боли с программиста. А то что повышается потребление ресурсов, то это имеет значение лишь в том случае, если ощутимо заметно для пользователя. В остальных случаях -- это серьёзная оптимизация времени программиста.

> В чем же причина такого массового распространения managed языков,

Видимо потому что программы исполняющиеся на виртуальных машинах легче переносить. Кроме того обычно такая среда предоставляет возможность работы с кодом как с данными, предоставляет большую гибкость.

> какую нишу они занимают, и какая судьба в будущем ждет языки вроде С,C++, Haskell, и т.д.?

Си похоже не умрёт никогда. Haskell, как жертва постоянных экспериментов и исследований -- тоже. Зато C++ очень даже может сдохнуть, ибо слишком сложен, и преимущества не стоят недостатков.

**UPD**: Нашёл очень [занятную дискуссию](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/Why_is_D_slower_than_LuaJIT_125080.html). Внезапно обнаружилось что реализация языка Lua, LuaJIT выполняется быстрее чем код на языке D. При том, что язык D -- статически типизированный, компилируется в нативный код, тогда как Lua -- динамически типизированный, с JIT-компиляцией. Такие дела.

Comment: Извините, а как долго Вы писали на C++?

Comment: недолго, где-то полгода. Потом я познакомился огромным количеством других, проработанных, изящных и гибких языков программирования, и считаю что имею право судить.

Comment: "Не писал, но осуждаю"

Comment: Пускай на С++ пишут драйвера или пусть какие еще спецы работают, но не всем же писать эту фигню

Comment: С++ в сфере прикладухи загибается, из последних Visual Studio убрали даже шаблон WinForms под него.

Comment: @z668 вообще-то это говорит о том, что загибается WinForms

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev ну тогда резонный вопрос - какая альтернатива winforms сейчас предоставляется в плюсах?

Comment: @z668: Судя по всему, альтернатива представляется не в плюсах, а _плюсам_: это C#. Он, кстати, в последнее время быстро развивается, один только async/await уже впереди планеты всей.

Comment: @VladD: заметил тенденцию, последнее время много программистов переходят с C++ на C#. Это заметно на кибере, много вопросов именно по нюансам и синтаксису + честные признания что переход с C++ на C#.

Comment: @VladimirGordeev .NET приложения могут превращаться в нативные https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/ Также можно для этого воспользоваться утилитой Ngen. Это к пункту "Что, если я хочу, чтобы мой код компилировался в машинный?".

Answer (score 9):

Выигрыш от использования managed languages, лучше всего виден на простом примере с J2ME (Java Mobile):

Вот представьте, вы разработчик проги для мобильного телефона. Количество ОС для мобильных устройств - ну хорошо если меньше 100. По факту у каждого производителя телефонов их штук по 5 по 6. Популярных осей для мобильных телефонов что-то порядка 20-ти. Итого, что я должен делать как разработчик? Фактически взять и написать прогу для десятка различных осей. При этом вынесем за скобку, что документации половину этих осей практически нет. За примером далеко ходить не будем и возьмем например [Nokia OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_OS), на котором работает 90% телефончиков (не смарфонов) Nokia. В общем это ночной кошмар разработчика.

В случае же managed language - в данном конкретное примере Java ME - все решается просто и изящно: вы все знаете как.

Для более серьезных систем - выигрыш не так может и очевиден, но все же по аналогии понятен.

Comment: Правда, относится ли J2ME в свете [этого опроделения](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code) к managed languages большой вопрос.

Comment: Ну это всего лишь определение Microsoft, но мы то понимаем, что Java относится к managed - по крайней мере топистартёр, Java тоже имел ввиду

Answer (score 8):

В попытке ответить на вопрос, можно сказать следующее:
    Специфические средства управления сложностью управляемых и интерпретируемых языков снимают большой процент нагрузки на программиста, как следствие удешевляют стоимость разработки и ускоряют её процесс. Эти языки не столь требовательны к квалификации и имеют низкий порог вхождения. Как следствие,  имеют более узкую (по разнообразию) область применения, удовлетворяя при этом большую часть спроса на ПО. По сему и имеют больше количество адептов.

Вообще инструмент по задаче. Болты молотком не закручивают.

Расставим точки над i:

Производительность:
Программы под виртуальные машины, а тем более интерпретаторы всегда будет более ресурсоемкими. 
    Нативный код с оптимизациями под конкретную платформу выполняется быстрее
    Детерминированное освобождение ресурсов сильно способствует сокращению их расхода
    Полное отсутствие возможности низкоуровневого программирования не позволяет управлять ресурсами с максимальной эффективностью

На практике можно рассмотреть следующий список задач, где managed языки практически неприменимы:

- lock-free алгоритм/структуру данных.
- Вычислительный алгоритм (численные алгоритмы или динамическое программирование приветствуется)
- ПО для встраиваемых систем
- Драйвер ;)
- Стек сетевых протоколов =))

А для тех, кто в танке пусть попробуют написать/найти реализацию (на дотнете или руби, например), так чтобы было быстрее нативных языков (С/С++ к примеру)

Парадигмы:
Метапрограммирование: надеюсь не будет открытием Америки факт доказательства того, что шаблоны С++ являются Тьюринг-полным языком. Кардинальное отличие от шаблонов Java/C#, которые больше похожи на макроподстановки с бонусами. Что это значит? Во первых значит что мы можем сделать любое вычисление еще на стадии компиляции, таким образом сокращая работу времени выполнения. Во вторых имеем инструмент (фактически язык в языке) для кодогенерации который означает возможность введения любой парадигмы без модификации языка:

- Лямбда функции еще старого С++03
- Встраивание DSL
- Контрактное программирование
- Аспектно-ориентированное программирование
- Type-erasure
- Различного рода синтаксический сахар
- Compile-time контейнеры/алгоритмы
- etc.

Интересно было бы взглянуть, как все это будет выглядеть на том же руби, без форка или выпуска минорной версии языка

Кроссплатформенность:
Кроссплатформенность зависит не от языка, а от специфики задачи.

Comment: > ПО для встраиваемых систем

Однако, Java и туда проникла.

Comment: А на .NET вообще ОС есть: [Cosmos (операционная система)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_(%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)).

Comment: Кстати, шаблоны C++ - это штука хорошая, но обычно вычисления выполняюются не на стадии компиляции, а при выполнении. В то время как современные языки стремятся к максимальной динамичности, этот плюс сей весьма сомнителен. Как тут уже упоминали, в Java и .NET есть Reflection, то есть возможность на лету работать с исходным кодом как с данными.

Впрочем, болты действительно не закручивают молотком =)

Comment: Хороший анализ. Особенно обратите внимание на:

>Эти языки не столь требовательны к квалификации и имеют низкий порог вхождения.

Последствия очевидны.

Comment: @avp <> is popular in big companies, because it suits the way they write software. At big companies, software tends to be written by large (and frequently changing) teams of mediocre programmers. <> imposes a discipline on these programmers that prevents any one of them from doing too much damage. The price is that the resulting code is bloated with protocols and full of duplication. This is not too high a price for big companies, because their software is probably going to be bloated and full of duplication anyway. Paul Graham (В оригинале <> -- object-oriented programming :) )

Comment: @Dith а чем аргументирована неприменимость managed языков для lock-free алгоритмов и структур данных (особливо на структурах-то это как отражается) и вычислительного программирования?

Comment: Все дело в производительности. В мире многопоточности очень многое зависит от конкретной платформы, учет особенностей может дать огромную разницу в производительности. В вычислениях нужна максимальная скорость и/или минимальное потребление памяти.

Comment: @Dith откуда выводы? Поскольку весьма интересные идеи многопоточности сейчас отрабатываются в haskell (не managed, но минимализмом не пахнет), то интересно, как Вы пришли к таким выводам?

Comment: > А для тех, кто в танке пусть попробуют написать/найти реализацию (на дотнете или руби, например), так чтобы было быстрее нативных языков (С/С++ к примеру)

http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/Why_is_D_slower_than_LuaJIT_125080.html

Answer (score 1):

Помимо всего прочего, нужно еще помнить следующее:

1. Далеко не всем требуется более высокая скорость, предоставляемая языками, компилируемыми прямо в машинный код. Если вы пишете какое-нибудь веб-приложение, да еще и взаимодействующее с базой данных, то биться за каждый такт процессора вряд ли имеет смысл.
2. Тот же C# неотделим от .NET с его тысячами и тысячами классов на все случаи жизни (аналогично и Java), тогда как в стандартной библиотеке С++ этого нет, что требует искать сторонние решения
3. Тот же С++ в силу необходимости следить за памятью самостоятельно (а также более сложного и запутанного синтаксиса, большей низкоуровневости и много чего еще) является языком с более высоким порогом входа, нежели Java и C# (не говоря уж о php и javascript)

Comment: @DreamChild: а вы о JIT слыхали? C# и Java уже давно компилируются в самый что ни на есть машинный код.

Comment: это каким-то образом противоречит тому, что я сказал?

Comment: >не говоря уж о php и javascript

не скажите, на js даже [числа сравнивать](http://hashcode.ru/questions/183519/) без посторонней помощи тяжело

Comment: Насчет "искать сторонние решения для С++" - это бредовая позиция. 
Изначально, по цели своего создания, С++ это не мегамонстр как "система .NET". У .NET - другие цели создания. Сравнивать "стандартные" библиотеки просто глупо. Например, в мире веб-программирования никому и в голову не приходит жаловаться, что в стандартную библиотеку Python не входят веб-фреймворки - не проблема взять и использовать десятки отличных фреймворков... А в мире Java даже наоборот - не смотря на наличие "стандартных" средств существует множество альтернативных библиотек для веб-разработки.

Comment: >Насчет "искать сторонние решения для С++" - это бредовая позиция

почему же бредовая? Речь, о том что в C#/java прямо "из коробки" есть огромное количество всяческих средств - и работа с сетью, и с бд, и с xml и с файловой системой и много чего еще. В С++ всего этого "из коробки"  нет. Это определенно является преимуществом, даже несмотря на то, что для С++ все это также можно найти в составе других библиотек - ведь в случае с вышеперечисленными языками над этим совсем не надо задумываться

Comment: В JVM не используется компиляция в машинный код всей программы. Компилируются только часто используемые куски. Это связано с тем, что расходы на компиляцию в машинный код значительные и редко используемые куски приложения дешевле интерпретировать, чем компилировать в байт-код.

Comment: И еще: наличие сборщика мусора не снимает с нас необходимость "следить за памятью". Утечки памяти в Java более коварны, чем в C и их труднее отследить, если не вникать в принципы работы Garbage collector'a.